# Keep running a script when changing the page in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So, let's say a I have two pages: "index.html" and "info.html".
In the page index.html, I have a button and a span. When the button is pressed, a countdown timer starts in that span - when the timer gets to zero, something happens. The issue is, if I start the countdown, then I go and check the info.html page, when I return to index.html, the timer resets. Of course this is caused by the script being unloaded when leaving index.html... but how to solve this? If i have something like 50 seconds remaining on the countdown, and I leave index.html, then I stay 30 seconds in the page info.html, when I come back I should have 20 seconds left. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Saving timer checkpoints in cookie or using shared webworkers(for asynchronous math in background)

Comment: Make some cookie value that will increment every second  using (`setInterval`) in your index.html, and will continue in any other page

Comment: When the timer starts, store the target time (when it'll be at zero) in a local cookie.  On each page, read the cookie and start a timer counting down to that target.  (Don't store the *remaining seconds* in the cookie, or the timer will drift as pages unload and load.  Store the *target* which doesn't change.)

Comment: Folks, **please** don't suggest cookies for purely client-side related information. [Web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) is your friend that won't bloat HTTP requests.

Comment: Use sessionStorage or localStorage to save the value while leaving the page, and access it wile arriving back on the page. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Instead of leaving `index.html` and loading `info.html`, stay on `index.html`, and load the new data you need via ajax and display it on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the time remaining in the local storage. When the page is refreshed the script will load the value from the local storage and start the timer with the new value:

```
function nonStopTimer(cb, seconds) {
  var KEY = 'nonStopTimer'
  var secsRemaining = localStorage[KEY];

  if (!secsRemaining) {
    secsRemaining = seconds;
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    localStorage[KEY] = null;
    cb();
  }, secsRemaining * 1000);

  setInterval(function() {
    secsRemaining -= 1;
    localStorage[KEY] = secsRemaining;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this looks fine, thank you! I will give it a try.

Comment: Let me know if there are any issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the timer information in local storage or session storage (see: [Web Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)).

So for instance, on page load:

```
var countdownEndsAt = localStorage.getItem("countdownEndsAt");
if (countdownEndsAt) {
    countdownEndsAt = +countdownEndsAt;
    if (countdownEndsAt < Date.now() {
        // It's already happened, decide what to do
    }
}
if (!countdownEndsAt) { // Separate 'if' in case you decide to clear it in the "it's already happened" above
    countdownEndsAt = Date.now() + 60000;
    localStorage.setItem("countdownEndsAt", countdownEndsAt); // Gets converted to a string
}
```

`countdownEndsAt` now contains the time value at which the timer should go off.